# Android Studio Dolphin: Unable to start emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to test out my app on newest Android 13 but after an update I cant start any emulators. I killed all zombie processes in task manager, restarted Android Studio and PC completely and still cant run it. Getting this error below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, from the option menu select:

[image: Select show on Disk]

File Explorer will open, from there delete files which have an extension of `*.lock`:

[image: delete *.lock files]

If there are no `*.lock` files, Open task manager and find the process `qemu-system-x86_64.exe` and end task.

Then try to start the emulator again, this time it should start.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced something like that.. try to delete the emulator then delete the file in `c:/user/android/avd/` then find the emulator file name then delete it..then recreate the emulator and try running it, hope it helps